# Payara asadmin command to monitor a specific resource

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3, monitor, payara, asadmin

Does anyone know the asadmin command line equivalent to display the Resource data as shown in the image below (ie the Resource __TimerPool)?

I'm using Payara 4.1.1.171.1.

[image]

I typed `asadmin monitor --help` and it provided this as

> ```
>        monitor [--help]
>        --type type
>        [--filename filename]
>        [--interval interval]
>        [--filter filter]
>        instance-name
> ```

The type field only accepts "httplistener", "jvm" and "webmodule" as inputs.
So I can't use a "resource" or "jdbcpool" as a type.

Oddly enough in the old glassfish 2.1 https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19879-01/821-0185/gelol/index.html you can select "jdbcpool" as the type

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't really find the answer on the payara documentation https://docs.payara.fish/documentation/payara-server/monitoring-service/monitoring-service.html

But using part of the glassfish documentation https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/ghmct.html#gipzv I was able to get what I needed.

The command is `asadmin get --monitor server.resources.__TimerPool.*`

This then returns (this is a partial output):

> server.resources.__TimerPool.numconnused-highwatermark = 2
>   server.resources.__TimerPool.numconnused-lastsampletime =
>   1559826720029 server.resources.__TimerPool.numconnused-lowwatermark =
>   0 server.resources.__TimerPool.numconnused-name = NumConnUsed
>   server.resources.__TimerPool.numconnused-starttime = 1559823838730
>   server.resources.__TimerPool.numconnused-unit = count
>   server.resources.__TimerPool.numpotentialconnleak-count = 0
>   server.resources.__TimerPool.numpotentialconnleak-description = Number
>   of potential connection leaks
>   server.resources.__TimerPool.numpotentialconnleak-lastsampletime = -1
>   server.resources.__TimerPool.numpotentialconnleak-name =
>   NumPotentialConnLeak
>   server.resources.__TimerPool.numpotentialconnleak-starttime =
>   1559823838735 server.resources.__TimerPool.numpotentialconnleak-unit =
>   count server.resources.__TimerPool.waitqueuelength-count = 0
>   server.resources.__TimerPool.waitqueuelength-description = Number of
>   connection requests in the queue waiting to be serviced.
>   server.resources.__TimerPool.waitqueuelength-lastsampletime = -1
>   server.resources.__TimerPool.waitqueuelength-name = WaitQueueLength
>   server.resources.__TimerPool.waitqueuelength-starttime = 1559823838735
>   server.resources.__TimerPool.waitqueuelength-unit = count
>
> Command get executed successfully.

It's important to add the **.*** at the end of the asadmin command in `asadmin get --monitor server.resources.__TimerPool.*`

If you neglect that and just enter `asadmin get --monitor server.resources.__TimerPool` it'll return

> No monitoring data to report.
>
> Command get executed successfully.

To see thelist of resources you have available to you to monitor type `/asadmin list --monitor server.resources.*`